# Install RVM (Ruby) on a macbook and SiriProxy

Tags: ruby, rvm

i'm trying to install rvm on my mac and i think i got that, now i'm trying to install the siriproxy and i get this:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Helder-Sousa:SiriProxy sousa$ sudo gem install /Users/sousa/SiriProxy/pkg/siriproxy-0.3.0.gemERROR:  Error installing /Users/sousa/SiriProxy/pkg/siriproxy-0.3.0.gem:
    siriproxy requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
MacBook-Pro-de-Helder-Sousa:SiriProxy sousa$
```

The thing is, that i have installed the latest RVM, shouldn't i get the latest Ruby version?

Thanks very much guys!

Comment: Just to expand on Igor's answer: RVM let's you MANAGE Ruby versions; it doesn't install them automatically. You have to ask it to! Also, you should not use `sudo` to install gems if you are using RVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you need to install ruby.

```
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm 1.9.3
gem install /Users/sousa/SiriProxy/pkg/siriproxy-0.3.0.gem
```

But when you close terminal your ruby version is back to system(1.8.7), don't forget `rvm 1.9.3` in next time or change system ruby by `rvm 1.9.3 --default`